# Glide show only first image

Tags: java, android, image, android-fragments, android-glide

I load different images between tabs.Each of tabs has got instance of fragment Solution.
But pic shows only on first tab and I dont know why. With picasso library I have the same problem.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    pic = getArguments().getString("pic");
}


public void onViewCreated(final View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    img = view.findViewById(R.id.pic);
    Glide.with(view.getContext())
            .load(pic)
            .into(img);



}
public static Solution newInstance(int sectionNumber, String[] array, String zadani, String [] pic){

    Solution fragment = new Solution();

    Bundle bundle1 = new Bundle();
    String section;
    section = array[sectionNumber];
    String p;
    p = pic [sectionNumber];
    bundle1.putString("key", section);
    bundle1.putString("pic", p);


    bundle1.putString("zadani", zadani);

    fragment.setArguments(bundle1);
    return fragment;



}
```

Page adapter of Fragment

```
public Fragment getItem(int position) {


    return Solution.newInstance(position, array,zadani, pic);

}
```

}`

Comment: probably `pic` contains the same value?

Comment: No, the pic load correctly, every tabfragment pic has got different String url.